# Calling a method in a script from HTML. The script is indirectly referred to in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html which has this:

```
<head><script src="script1.js"></script></head>
<body><script>myFunc();</script></body>
```

The script1.js has code that internally refers to script2.js like this :

```
var js = document.createElement(""script""); js.type = ""text/javascript""; 
js.src = ""script2.js"";
```

script2.js contains this :

```
function myFunc() {
    alert "Hi!";
}
```

I need to now refer to this method in script2.js directly from the html. But I am not able to achieve the same. I get an error saying myFunc is not defined. (Debugged in Mozilla)
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you have two doublequotes around the strings in `script1.js`?

Comment: The obvious problem would be the double quotes around your strings (`""text/javascript""`), but I'm guessing that's not really in your code, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made quite a few mistakes:

1. **Watch your double quotes**, `(""script"")` should be `("script")`, as should all the places you've used double quotes.
2. In myFunc(), **alert needs brackets**, put brackets around the string `"Hi!"`, so should be: `alert("Hi!");`
3. You need to **append your script tag** to the body: `document.body.appendChild(js);`

So the final code should look more like:

```
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.src = "script2.js";
document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Also, when referring to your script2 functions within the html, wrap them in this code:

```
window.js.onload = function(){
    // functions from script 2 go here
    myFunc();
}
```

This stops the functions from running before myscript2 has loaded.

Here's the final code:

```
<head><script src="myscript1.js"></script></head>
<!-- myscript1.js

window.js = document.createElement("script");
js.src = "script2.js";
document.body.appendChild(js);

-->
<body>
<script>
window.js.onload = function(){
    myFunc();
    /*
     * All your myscript2 functions can go here
     */
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in first JavaScript file:

```
var jsfile = document.createElement("script");
jsfile.type = "text/javascript";
jsfile.src = TheFilePathOfSecondJsFile;
document.body.appendChild(jsfile);
```

I think you don't append it.

Answer (score 0):

First be careful with your double quote : 
`document.createElement(""script"");` => `document.createElement("script");`
`js.type = ""text/javascript"";` => `js.type = "text/javascript";`
...

Then at the end of script1.js write it :

```
var js = document.createElement(""script""); js.type = ""text/javascript""; 
js.src = ""script2.js"";
document.body.appendChild( js );
```